# How to avoid checking object in object to exists in data Vue.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

```
<template>
        <img :src="user.avatar_thumbnail">
        <a :href="user.profile.link"/>
    </template>
    <script>
        export default {
            data: function () {
                user: {}
            },
            mounted: function() {
                let vm = this;
                axios.get('user/profile/<id>').then((response) => {
                    vm.user = response.data.user
                });
            }
        }

    </script>
```

if server does not send field 'avatar_thumbnail' in object user so page isn't rendered,

so i can user if else expression (ternary) but I can't do it everywhere

```
    <img :src="user.avatar_thumbnail ? user.avatar_thumbnail : '' ">
```

maybe has vuejs some tool for this situation?

and more server send like this objects (nested): user.profile.avatar_thumbnail and I don't want to make nested ternary expression (please do not recommend me use computed methods - I'll be use this if I can't find another solution)

Comment: Maybe replace your ternary with a boolean and use v-if?

Comment: @tomerpacific yea I can, but i don't want this

Comment: you should have a unique wrapper for all yours elements

Comment: i'll suggest use computer property and use it in your :src

Answer (score 0):

```html
 <img :src="user.avatar_thumbnail || '' ">
```

or:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining

and, correct

```js
  export default {
            data: function () {
                return { 
                   user: {}
               }
            },
```

Comment: what's happen if i have object in object in object like this user.profile.avatar.thumbnail

Comment: `user?.profile?.avatar?.thumbnail || ''`    [Optional_chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining)

Comment: You can encapsulate a method yourself to implement `Optional_chaining`,  or  https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-proposal-optional-chaining

Comment: YES YES!!! Thank you very much. This is what I was looking for

Comment: Okey, on monady I'll try use this in project, and I give feedback :)

Answer (score 0):

There are many different different way to resolve your issues. But in your given code there are many errors. you can try this solution

```
 <template>
  <div>
    <img :src="getThumbnail()" />
    <a :href="user.profile.link" />
  </div>
</template>
        <script>
export default {
  data: function() {
    return{
    user: {}
    }
  },
  methods: {
    getThumbnail() {
      if (this.user.avatar_thumbnail) {
        return this.user.avatar_thumbnail
      } else {
        return 'default_thumbnil'
      }
    }
  },
  mounted: function() {
    let vm = this
    axios.get('user/profile/<id>').then(response => {
      vm.user = response.data.user
    })
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: i will recommend to use computed property, and use it in :src, and you can use methods that already i have shown.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out to be quite simple, just set a default value to the object with the same structure as the object that you're gonna receive. For example:

```js
data: function () {
  user: {
    avatar_thumbnail: '',
    profile: {
      link: ''
    }
  }
}
```

You can also define a function that return the `initial` data, like so:

```js
const initialUser = () => {
  return {
    avatar_thumbnail: '',
    profile: {
      link: ''
    }
  }
}
```

Then use it in the data property:

```js
data: function () {
  user: initialUser()
}
```

Note: You might only need to specify the properties of the object which are used in the template to overcome the potential errors.